# Draw Hexagon in Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, trigonometry

i need to write a function that draws an hexagone like shown below into an 2d array. I only know the column size of the array, the rest needs to be calculated.

[image]

However, I'm struggling with the mathmatics behind it.

This is what i've coded so far:

```js
function deg2rad(degrees) {
  const pi = Math.PI;
  return degrees * (pi / 180);
}

function getCos(deg) {
  return Math.cos(deg2rad(deg));
}


function drawHexagon(cols) {
  // upper left corner
  const rows = parseInt(cols * getCos(30), 10);

  const arr = [...Array(rows)].map(() => Array(cols).fill(''));
  for (let i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
      if (j > Math.floor(cols / 4) - 1 && j < (cols - Math.round(10 / 4))) { // middle section (square)
        arr[i][j] = 1;
        continue;
      }

      if (i < Math.floor(rows / 2)) { // top half

        if (j < Math.floor(cols / 4)) { // left side (triangle)
          if (rows / 2 / (i + 1) < cols / 4 / (cols / 4 - j)) { // seems to be right
            arr[i][j] = 2;
          }
        } else { // right side (triangle)
          if (rows / (i + 1) < cols / (j / 4 + 1)) { // wrong
            arr[i][j] = 2;
          }
        }
      } else { // bottom half

        if (j < Math.floor(cols / 4)) { // Left side
          if (rows / (i + 1) > cols / 4 / (j + 1)) { // seems to be right
            arr[i][j] = 2;
          }
        } else { // bottom right 
          if (rows / 2 / (i + 1) > cols / 4 / (cols - j)) { // wrong
            arr[i][j] = 2;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(arr); // console.table() not available in snippet
  return arr;
}
drawHexagon(8)
```

Outputting the array will give me this:

[image]

So the left side and middle section seems to be right.

I'd be really glad if someone could help me out on this one.

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please fix the console errors

Comment: thanks, i edited it. however, snippet can't make use of `console.table()` Using `console.log()` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems, The First one is that **Math.sin ()** and **Math.cos ()** returns the result with some f**loating point error**, Therefore calculations not stable.

The second is the **geometric  calculations**, you forgot the **hypotenuse**, As figure shows that **the triangle must be a right angle triangle.**

[image]

## **The Solution:**

1- Calculate the length of the **side b** as you do then get the **hypotenuse (c)** and check it.

2- if **a²+b² = c²** then **(a, b, c)** are valid sides,  else get the closest possible sides forms right angle triangle.

3- Set points inside array as a 2d grid (**As the figure above**).

4- **Connecting points**. The most **efficient solution** I guess is to get the **shortest path** as in these figure and normal connections between the lines, the shortest path is the line itself.

5- Return the array containing the path, then assign value for each cell in the grid using path array

**Here link contained my implementation, but (without shortest path function, I left the function empty)**

[Javascript-Code](https://playcode.io/574872)